# Php - upload file to special characters directory

Tags: php, laravel, upload, special-characters

I'm having problems when try to save a file in a directory with special characters... for example I have the directory `recepção` and it creates a new folder named `RecepÃ§Ã£o` and put the file there.

I'm using laravel framework and I save the file this way:

```
Input::file('file')->move('/recepção', 'file.pdf');
```

How can I solve this problem?

Thank you

Comment: How about `utf8_encode()` ?

Comment: use like this --- ->move(utf8_encode('/recepção'), 'file.pdf'); ? @roberto06

Comment: Yep. Could be `utf8_decode()` though. Try both `Input::file('file')->move(utf8_encode('/recepção'), 'file.pdf');` and `Input::file('file')->move(utf8_decode('/recepção'), 'file.pdf');` and tell me if it worked

Comment: works with utf8_decode() thank you @roberto06

Comment: No worries mate. I'm adding this as an answer, please mark it as accepted so it can help others in the future.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to use [`utf8_decode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.utf8-decode.php), as such :

```
Input::file('file')->move(utf8_decode('/recepção'), 'file.pdf');
```